VISSIM Matlab COM interface optimization problem
I m trying to perform optimisation in MAtlab to obtain the best set of  car following parameters of Weidmann 99 model. The code is as follows :function optimize_vissim_params()
% Lower and upper bounds for the parameters
LB = [1 0 -20 -5 0.1 0.1 -1 0 0];
UB = [5 10 0 0 5 20 1 8 8];
% Define the number of variables
nvars = length(LB);

% Define the acceptable RMSE range
acceptableRange = [0.012, 0.0146];  % Example range
acceptableRange1 = [1.42, 1.7358];  % Example range for headway

% Specify which variables should be integers
IntCon = 1;  % Index of the parameter that should be an integer

% Set up GA options
options = optimoptions('ga', ...
    'MaxGenerations', 100, ...
    'PopulationSize', 50, ...
    'CrossoverFcn', @crossoverscattered, ... 
    'CrossoverFraction', 0.8, ... 
    'MutationFcn', 'mutationadaptfeasible', ...
    'Display', 'iter', ...
    'PlotFcn', {'gaplotbestf'}, ...
    'OutputFcn', @(options, state, flag) stopIfInRange(options, state, flag, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1));

% Run the GA solver
[solution, objectiveValue] = ga(@(params) combinedObjectiveFunction(params, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1), nvars, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, [],IntCon, options);

% Display the results
[final_rmse, avg_headway] = rmsewithgivenparameter(solution);
disp(['Optimal parameters: ', num2str(solution)]);
disp(['Final RMSE value: ', num2str(final_rmse)]);
disp(['Final average headway value: ', num2str(avg_headway)]);

% Combined objective function to calculate a penalty-based sum of normalized RMSE and average headway
function combinedObjectiveValue = combinedObjectiveFunction(params, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1)
    [final_rmse, avg_headway] = rmsewithgivenparameter(params);

    % Normalize RMSE and average headway
    normalized_rmse = (final_rmse - acceptableRange(1)) / (acceptableRange(2) - acceptableRange(1));
    normalized_headway = (avg_headway - acceptableRange1(1)) / (acceptableRange1(2) - acceptableRange1(1));

    % Penalty if RMSE or average headway is outside acceptable ranges
    penalty = 0;
    if final_rmse < acceptableRange(1) || final_rmse > acceptableRange(2)
        penalty = penalty + 1000; % Arbitrary large value for penalty
    end
    if avg_headway < acceptableRange1(1) || avg_headway > acceptableRange1(2)
        penalty = penalty + 1000; % Arbitrary large value for penalty
    end

    % Combine the normalized objectives with penalties
    combinedObjectiveValue = normalized_rmse + normalized_headway + penalty;
end

% Custom output function to stop GA if combinedObjectiveValue is less than or equal to 2
function [state, options, optchanged] = stopIfInRange(options, state, flag, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1)
    optchanged = false;

    % Get the current best combined objective value
    [~, bestIdx] = min(state.Score);
    bestParams = state.Population(bestIdx,:);
    combinedObjectiveValue = combinedObjectiveFunction(bestParams, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1);

    % Check if the combined objective value is within the acceptable range
    if combinedObjectiveValue <= 2
        state.StopFlag = 'Custom stopping criterion met: Combined objective value is within the acceptable range.';
        disp(state.StopFlag);
    end
end

end"
I have fixed the first parameter value so only 9 values.
The code runs for few iterations but after some time error comes "Error using feval
Server Creation Failed: Server execution failed
Error in actxserver (line 89)
h=feval(['COM.' convertedProgID], 'server', machinename, interface);
Error in rmsewithgivenparameter (line 10)
Vissim = actxserver('Vissim.Vissim.22');
Error in optimize_vissim_params/combinedObjectiveFunction (line 168)
[final_rmse, avg_headway] = rmsewithgivenparameter(params);
Error in optimize_vissim_params>@(params)combinedObjectiveFunction(params,acceptableRange,acceptableRange1) (line 158)
[solution, objectiveValue] = ga(@(params) combinedObjectiveFunction(params, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1), nvars, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, [],IntCon, options);
Error in createAnonymousFcn>@(x)fcn(x,FcnArgs{:}) (line 11)
fcn_handle = @(x) fcn(x,FcnArgs{:});
Error in fcnvectorizer (line 19)
y(i,:) = feval(fun,(pop(i,:)));
Error in gaminlppenaltyfcn
Error in gapenalty
Error in makeState (line 76)
Score = FitnessFcn(state.Population(initScoreProvided+1:end,:));
Error in galincon (line 24)
state = makeState(GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,Iterate,output.problemtype,options);
Error in gapenalty
Error in ga (line 408)
[x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = gapenalty(FitnessFcn,nvars,...
Error in optimize_vissim_params (line 158)
[solution, objectiveValue] = ga(@(params) combinedObjectiveFunction(params, acceptableRange, acceptableRange1), nvars, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, [],IntCon, options);
Caused by:
Failure in user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue.
Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue.
I want to know if this error is due to VISSIM improper COM instalation or is there any issue with the code.

The issue is in this line
Vissim = actxserver('Vissim.Vissim.22');

Each time the ga is asked to compute the objective function value, it opens a new instance of the program which might cause a problem. Maybe you ran out of available licenses, and it doesn't want to open.
It should be something like this
persistent Vissim
if isempty(Vissim)
    Vissim = actxserver('Vissim.Vissim.22');
end
% rest of code

In this case, because I don't see how you interact with the software itself, you have to make sure that once the simulation is done, you run the commands that will "prepare" the software for the next run, i.e. close current simulation file.
